# sftp not working, but ssh is working

Tags: linux, ssh, nat, sftp, pfsense

I have a nat rule in my firewall to allow port 22 traffic through pfsense. I am able to SSH into my server but sftp through filezilla is getting timed out and not connecting.

I tried with the local ip of the server and sftp worked fine. The only problem is when it pass through pfsense.

Not sure why sftp is not working behind the NAT. At the same time SSH works without any issue.

Comment: It appears that you have forgotten to ask a question. It would also be good to see logs from the server and the client.

Comment: Give me output of this command: telnet <ip> 22

Comment: Sounds like an issue in filezilla. Are you definitely connecting using *SFTP* and not FTPS?

Comment: Try another SFTP client, perhaps [PSFTP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (aka PuTTY).

Comment: Provide a screenshot of pfsense rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following and it fixed the issue.

- Re-added the NAT rule for port 22 in pfsense
- Upgraded Filezilla to latest version.